# Applying regex for data that spans multiple lines - "gm" flags don't work

Tags: javascript, regex, multiline

I have source data that looks like this:

```
ab

ab
```

I run the following on it:

```
function lintPost(postText) {
    var replacements = {
        a : "4",
        b : "BBBB"
    }

    for (var pattern in replacements) {
      if (replacements.hasOwnProperty(pattern)) {
        var postText = postText.replace(pattern, replacements[pattern], "gm");
        console.log(postText);
      }
    }
    return postText;
};
```

I get back the following:

```
4BBBB

ab
```

Meaning, despite using both the global and multiline flags, the regexen are still only applied to the first line - JS seems to stop matching at the first line-break.

The output SHOULD be

```
4BBBB

4BBBB
```

I tried with just g, with just m, even with y - nothing.

Why doesn't JavaScript match the other lines in my source data?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MDN states:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

> The use of the flags parameter in the String.replace method is non-standard. Instead of using this parameter, use a RegExp object with the corresponding flags.

So change your code that way:

```
var postText.replace(new RegExp(pattern,"gm"), replacements[pattern]);
```

Comment: Wow. You, sir, are a genius. Should have read MDN more carefully! This solution works - I will accept once 5 mins elapse and SO lets me. Thank you!

Comment: @ezuk btw, you don't need the `m` flag in that case.